# Using design pattern with modules

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

As I understand: in Ruby, we use modules instead of classes when we don't need a state; if it's just a function that takes an input an produces an output.

Some design patterns depend on inheritance, like the [template design pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/template_pattern.htm).

I am making a crawling library that takes a link as an input and produces an object containing the data.

It don't need a state so a module seems to be suitable for me instead of a class. I also need to use the template design pattern as I am using different algorithms to produce data with the same structure. I need to use inheritance to implement template design pattern, but I don't need a state; it just returns the data from the website.

Is implementing a design pattern a good reason to use classes (for inheritance)? What is the best practice in such cases?

Comment: Write automated tests for all your code, and then refactor your code when you learn how to improve its design. Your question assumes the code's design will be set in stone; this is wrong. Read books like /Refactoring to Patterns/ by Josh Kerievsky to get the hang of designing like this.

Comment: Note that Ruby supports (mixin) inheritance for modules, so your assumption that you need classes for inheritance is flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *In Ruby, we use modules instead of classes when we don't need a state; if it's just a function that takes an input an produces an output.*

That's *one* use of modules. Another use of modules is to provide what other languages would call "traits", sets of functionality which can be plugged into any class without inheritance. This can and often does include storing state.

Be sure to remain flexible, Ruby is a very flexible language.

---

> *It don't need a state so a module seems to be suitable for me instead of a class. I also need to use the template design pattern as I am using different algorithms to produce data with the same structure.*

Design patterns provide a *pattern* for solving certain general problems, not a set of rules which must be strictly adhered to. Many were written with C++ or Java in mind, extremely class-centric languages, and require some adapting to other languages.

In your case, all that matters is the interface remains the same. Rather than creating a whole abstract class, all you need to do is define an interface. Some languages have formal interfaces, like Rust or Java. Ruby does not. Instead it uses [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Basically if it has the methods you need and says it works like you need, use it.

```
module DoThatThing
  module ThisProvider
    def link_to_object(link)
      ...code to convert a link to ThisProvider into an object...

      return object
    end
  end

  module ThatProvider
    def link_to_object(link)
      ...code to convert a link to ThatProvider into an object...

      return object
    end
  end
end
```

Now it doesn't matter if you have `DoThatThing::ThisProvider` or `DoThatThing::ThatProvider`, you use them the same.

```
obj = provider_module.link_to_object(link)
```

You can, if you really want to, [implement formal abstract modules in Ruby](https://www.metabates.com/2011/02/07/building-interfaces-and-abstract-classes-in-ruby/), but *in Ruby* it's generally a wasted effort and very much goes against how one does things *in Ruby* (in other languages, absolutely create an interface).

Instead, enforce this with testing. [RSpec shared examples](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-dry-out-your-rspec-tests-using-shared-examples-d5cc5d33fd76), or a similar feature of your testing system, are a good way to do that. You write one set of tests which should work for any implementation of `DoThatThing` and run them for all implementations of `DoThatThing`.

```
RSpec.shared_examples 'DoThatThing' do
  ...shared tests for any DoThatThing...
end


RSpec.describe DoThatThing::ThisProvider do
  include_examples "DoThatThing"

  ...tests specific to ThisProvider...
end

RSpec.describe DoThatThing::ThatProvider do
  include_examples "DoThatThing"

  ...tests specific to ThatProvider...
end
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. In the example of modules you introduced, the "code to convert a link ..." has some common lines like creating the object to be returned and the way that object is being filled. Is it DRY to repeat it ?

Comment: @hassanalmorsy Sharing code between modules gets a bit awkward, so look back at the assumptions. `link_to_object` takes a url and produces an object. Could this be done instead as a class method on each applicable class? `obj = SomeClass.from_link(link)` If there's logic to determine which class to instantiate, is this a factory? `obj = LinkFactory.new(link)` If you find you really, really just need to inherit behavior, make `DoThatThing` a module with the common methods and have implementations include it. Or make it a class and inherit, there's nothing which says classes *must* hold state.

Comment: @hassanalmorsy For cross-cutting concerns, look into [service objects](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial). These are great for code which uses a bunch of classes together, or which encodes business logic which isn't fundamental to the objects. For example, if you wanted to add users to lists `List#add_user` would be very simple but the business logic can make it complex. Instead of making `List#add_user` complex and less flexible, write `ListManager#add_user` which contains the business logic and calls `List#add_user`.

Comment: Thanks, I got you